# Nashorn : are nashorn's js objects extensible

Tags: nashorn

I've an issue with nashorn where i want to extend the `JFrame` instance.

The following code

```js
print(Object.isExtensible(frame));
```

Where `frame` is the instance. Well this line throws a `TypeError`, while :

```js
Object.prototype.toString.call(frame)
```

returns `[Object javax.swing.JFrame]`

meaning it is an object whose constructor is `javax.swing.JFrame`. 
I'm confused and would like some suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java objects by themselves are not extensible (JavaScript objects are.)

You have two options:

1. Wrap the Java object in a JavaScript object *or*
2. Use Java.extend to create a subclass.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html

Comment: Exactly , but still it looked a bit awkward to me so had to be sure.

Comment: How do you "wrap" a Java object in a JS object?